# Cloudfront/S3 Caching Issue

Tags: cache-control, amazon-cloudfront, expires-header

We have moved our static web content to [Amazon's CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), backed by S3. We've [successfully applied the caching-related meta data to the objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504091/aws-s3-setting-metadata-with-the-php-sdk2/16556626#16556626), and when viewing the response headers for the following object, the Cache-Control and Expires headers look correct:

https://dwxl1a3pmrzl.cloudfront.net/img/hdr/logoRoots.1.0.0.png

However, when viewing the object in Chrome's Developer Tools, the object seems to be retrieved each time rather than cached. Is this a problem with the object itself in that the headers are set incorrectly, or the expected behavior for the Developer Tools when viewing a stand-alone image?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that chrome by default disables caching when the web inspector is open.  To confirm that browser side caching is working, go into the dev tools settings (the little gear icon at the bottom right of the web inspector), and uncheck "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" in the General section of the settings.